# Como filtrar campos selecionados através do Spring JPA usando JPQL?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

Gostaria de saber como proceder para filtrar campos selecionados usando JPQL dentro da implementação do JPA/Hibernate?

Será aprensetado o seguinte cenário para facilitar a compreensão, segue diagrama de classe abaixo:

[image: Diagrama de classe onde demostra relacionamento de uma entidade Person e Phone]

É importante apresentar a estratégia de relacionamento usada. A classe person é apenas uma entidade formal, contendo campos e configurações padrões. Mas, o relacionamento com Phone segue a seguinte estratégia:

```
    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(
            name = "phones",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "person_id"),
            uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "number"),
            schema = "profile",
            indexes = {@Index(columnList = "number")}
    )
    private Set<PhoneEntity> phones = new HashSet<>();
```

Já, a classe Phone, segue a seguinte implementação:

```
@Data
@Embeddable
public class PhoneEntity {

    @Column(length = 9)
    private String number;

    @Column(length = 2)
    private String areaCode;

}
```

É usado a estratégia `@ElementCollection` pelo fato de ser uma classe simples.

Logo, como fazer para pegar apenas os telefones em uma consulta? Ex:

```
select p.phones from Person p;
```

Comment: Você pode tentar fazer explicitando o join: `SELECT ph FROM Person p JOIN p.phones ph`. Chegou a testar assim?

Comment: Como seria o meu tipo de retorno?

Comment: Um `Set<PhoneEntity>`

Comment: Eu consegui resolver aqui, @Dherik. Na verdade, eu não consigo criar um Repository para ele até porque ele é uma entidade. Mas, por outro lado, criei um serviço e um controle somente para tratar negócios pertinentes a entidade Phone. Obrigado! Caso queira responder a pergunta, validarei ela como resposta válida. Gratidão!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode tentar fazer explicitando o join:

```
SELECT ph FROM Person p JOIN p.phones ph
```

E o retorno esperado é o mesmo do mapeamento da entidade:

```
Set<PhoneEntity>
```

O código final ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
String jpql = "SELECT ph FROM Person p JOIN p.phones ph";
Query query = em.createQuery(jpql);

Set<PhoneEntity> phones = query.getResultList();
```